# Using ReSharper to Sort Members by Type then Name

Tags: c#, resharper

I've been trying to get ReSharpers Code Cleanup to not only sort any members alphabetically by  name, but to sort them primarily by their type (whether that be a methods return type or a properties type etc.), then by their name.

For example:

```
#region " Properties "

public string Name { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }

#endregion

#region " Instance Methods "

public void SecondMethod()...
public void FirstMethod()...
public Post GetPost()...
public List<Post> GetPosts()...

#endregion
```

Would become:

```
#region " Properties "

public int Age { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

#endregion

#region " Instance Methods "

public List<Post> GetPosts()...
public Post GetPost()...
public void FirstMethod()...
public void SecondMethod()...

#endregion
```

Ideally, I would like the other default behaviours to remain the same e.g. where Constructors, Properties are positioned/grouped, and if a number of members appear within a region (as in the example above), for that group of members to be sorted independently from members outside of that group/region.

Can anyone recommend the code necessary within the ReSharper Type Members Layout pattern editor to achieve this please?

Comment: Do you mean just the return type for methods?

Comment: Actually, I'll update the title of the question as it's not just Methods. I'd like return types for Methods and Property Types to be sorted on first. I still want to retain the default ordering of where constructors, properties, methods etc. appear within a class but within each of these groupings, instead of just sorting by member name, sort by type first, then name.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but it's possible you could write a [plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Plugin+Development) to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the Type Member Layout in Resharper, I'm guessing this isn't possible. Here's a sample snippet for the events region:

```
<Entry>
    <Match>
        <Kind Is="event"/>
    </Match>
    <Sort>
        <Access Order="public internal protected-internal protected private" />
        <Static />
        <Name/>
    </Sort>
    <Group Region="Events"/>
</Entry>
```

Here's an article from JetBrains themselves: [In-depth look at customizing type layout with resharper](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/).

It looks like there is no qualifier for return type for sorting unfortunately. Here are the options, referenced in that post:

```
 - <Kind Is=”$val” [Order=”$val”]>
 - <Name Is="$val” [IgnoreCase=”true/false”]>
 - <HasAttribute CLRName=”$val” [Inherit=”true/false”]>
 - <Access Is=”$val”>
 - <Static/>
 - <Abstract/>
 - <Virtual/>
 - <Sealed/>
 - <Readonly/>
 - <ImplementsInterface CLRName=”$val” [Immediate=”true/false”]>
 - <HandlesEvent/>
```

You could contact JetBrains and request that a new operand be added to the list. Seems fairly simple. Could be something like:

```
<ReturnType="$val" [Order="$val"][AlphaOrder="true/false"]>
```